# Recursive Merge sort and Stack Frames in Python

Tags: python, recursion, merge, mergesort

The following code (not mine, just studying it) bounces (correctly) between recursing over the original list (i.e., `list_`), and the merge routine. The flow of the stack frames (i.e., how and why they are returning the way they are is unclear, even when watching in Python Tutor, which is what I recount below). A description of how the code returns and questions follow the program.

```
def merge(left, right):
    if not len(left) or not len(right):
        return left or right

    result = []
    i, j = 0, 0
    while (len(result) < len(left) + len(right)):
        if left[i] < right[j]:
            result.append(left[i])
            i+= 1
        else:
            result.append(right[j])
            j+= 1
        if i == len(left) or j == len(right):
            result.extend(left[i:] or right[j:])
            break 

    return result

def mergesort(list_):
    if len(list_) < 2:
        return list_

    middle = len(list_)//2
    left = mergesort(list_[:middle])
    right = mergesort(list_[middle:])

    return merge(left, right)


list_ = [7,5,2,1,3]

print(mergesort(list_))
```

The first recursive call we hit is `left` (we want to sort the left half of the list, and then the left half of the left half, etc., until we get to a list of size one and hit the base case).  This works fine. We go from [7,5,2,1,3] to [7,5] to [7] and hit the base case. So far, so good. **I expect stack frames to start returning, but that's not really what happens. I think it returns the 7, but then we jump to the next set of recursion calls for `right`.** The 5 reappears. The 5 appeared in the stack frame immediately before the 7, so things are returning in reverse order (which is good). The new parameters split off the 5 and create a single list, thus setting off the base case and returning 5.

Here's where it gets weird: The program proceeds to the merge step, which is correct. **How does it "know" to skip further recursing on `right` or `left` (I gave it an entire list, much of which is untouched) and jump to merge? Moreover, how does it know make it back to the mergesort function from merge, without explicit instruction, and know exactly where to pick up?** Can anyone shed some light on this? Traditional algorithm texts and most videos have been of zero help, as they do not address stack frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your confusion has to do with not understanding that each stack frame has it's own point of execution. Each time a function is called, the frame's execution pauses and a new frame is created for the function call. When it returns, the previous frame picks up right where it left off. There's no central place that "knows" where the code should go next, each level handles that for itself.

In the example scenario you described, the `mergesort` call for `[7, 5]` first splits the lists up into `[7]` and `[5]`, then recurses on each of them in turn to get `left` and `right`. When the second of those recursive calls has returned, it goes on to the next part of the code, which is the `merge` call, simply because that's what comes next in the code.

You can see the logic quite clearly, right here:

```
left = mergesort(list_[:middle])
right = mergesort(list_[middle:])

return merge(left, right)
```

This tells you that on this run (and every run that doesn't hit the base case), it's going to recurse twice and then `merge`.

Comment: That's definitely part of it. Also, I think I came into this thinking there was more finality in the return statements than there really is (i.e., return doesn't end the fxn, rather it returns a value). It comes from hearing, "Once you return something from your function, that's it! Nothing else can come after that." and carrying it a bit too far. Also, I don't really know what role the EIP plays in this, which would probably be of some help, but I like your less technical approach.

Comment: I think the statement you're quoting isn't wrong, it's just a bit confusing when you're dealing with multiple recursive calls to the same function. A `return` does end the execution of the current function, but it doesn't end the execution of its caller (even if that caller is the same function making a recursive call). The caller just goes on from where it was paused. So if you're six stack frames deep and you hit a `return` statement, the sixth frame is finished and you'll go back to the fifth stack frame and keep running its code.